# Displaying Map on JSP

Tags: jsp, dictionary

I have a Map of Account objects which I need to display on the JSP. I have followed the procedure but the UI doesn't display the table contents at all. Any advise would be very helpful.
Below is my code : 
Bean : Account.java ( ID,Name,RenewwalDate,balance,equityallocation)
Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getList(ModelMap model) {
    for (Iterator it = accounts.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Object key = it.next();
        Account value = accounts.get(key);
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + "Value : " + value.getName()
                + value.getBalance() + value.getEquityAllocation()
                + value.getRenewalDate() +value.getId());
    }
    System.out.println(accounts);
    model.addAttribute(accounts);
    return "account/list";
}
```

JSP Snippet :

```
  <h3>List of Accounts</h3>
        <form:form modelAttribute="accounts" method="post">
            <table>
                <c:forEach var="donor" items="${accounts}">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">${donor.key}</td>
                        <td align="right">${donor.value.name}</td>
                        <td align="right">  ${donor.value.balance}</td>
                        <td align="right">${donor.value.equityAllocation}</td>
                        <td align="right">${donor.value.renewalDate}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass attribute with name accounts, for example `model.addAttribute("accounts", accounts);`

Answer (score 1):

Set Modelattribute as `model.setAttribute("account",account)`. So the model will contain the map object as `${accounts}`.So just use `${account.keyname}` as your source of the data